# Default Order of Table List in Sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, information-schema

What is the default order of the table list in sqlite?

I have a database file from syslog-ng (Linux syslog).
I actually want to list the tables according to their sequence of creation.

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
```

When I execute this command through shell script, I get the tables list in the sequence they were created in. However, I want to be sure if that's the guaranteed behavior?  Or is there any possibility that I'll get the table list in random order? 
It's important for me to know because I want to keep the latest tables and drop the oldest ones.

Comment: The only way to guarantee a specific order of the output of a SELECT statement is to use `ORDER BY` - there is no alternative. So unless SQLite stores the creation time, you are out of luck

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be sure if that the guaranteed behavior? Or is there any possibility that I'll get the table list in random order?

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets of rows, meaning that there is no inherent ordering whatsoever. Without an `order by` clause, the order in which rows are returned is *undefined*, meaning that the database is free to order the rows as it likes.

So there is no guarantee that the order in which rows are returned is consistent across subsequent execuctions of the same query.

As far as concerns, `sqlite_master` does not store the date when each table was created - and I don't know any other SQLite system table that would hold this information.

In most databases, one option would be to set up a trigger on `create table` statements and store the information in some custom table, but I think SQLite does not support that type of trigger either.

Comment: My question is only about tables list order or sequence. I'm not concerned about rows within the table.

Comment: @Usman.3D: yes, I got that. `sqlite_master` is a table itself, so when you `select` from it, the above limitations do apply.